# I need a method to return a promise after nextTick (or timeout)

Tags: vuejs2

1. The method must return a Promise
2. That promise must be `new` on or after nextTick

So basically I need a method that starts executing before a tick and returns a value that is calculated after a tick.

```
methods:{
    myMethod: function(){
         // change this.$data effecting a computed val that is injected into a subelement prop
         //tick
         //grab the subelement by this.$ref
         //return something from that subelement that has been efected by the computed change
    }
}
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick > "returns a Promise if no callback is provided"

Comment: @chipit24 I know nextTick produces it's own promise.  I need to produce mine within this.$nextTick.then or .resolve or something.

Comment: Still not clear. Can you provide an example of what you're expecting? This sounds like an XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @chipit24 X/Y may very well be the case.  I'm not a Vue guru.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
primaryPromise: function(foo, bar) {
  // changing foo impacts computed props
  // some of those computed things effect the sub element bar
  this.foo = foo;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // a tick grants the time required for the
    // computed changes in foo to propagate into bar 
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      // the resulting sub-promise resolution
      // takes computed changes into account
      resolve(this.$refs[bar][0].subPromise());
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you could use an `async` function:

```js
async myMethod() {
  this.foo = "sup";
  await this.$nextTick();
  console.log(this.$refs.subelement.count);
}
```

An async function returns a promise, and allows you to use `await` to wait for any specified promises to resolve before continuing. I created a simple example of this on CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-6qny6.

If you want to execute code in response to an element being re-rendered or changed, it would be better to emit an event from that child component and listen to that event from the parent. Or, if you need that computed property in both the child and the parent, you could pull the logic for it out into the parent component and pass it down as a prop.

Comment: I like this, thanks for this, I did try an async/await approach.  Something about the third party sub-element didn't like it.  But definitely a keep-worthy answer you've posted.  I'm also gonna post 'cause I just got thru it.